# error in displaying datagrid values to textbox

Tags: c#, datagrid

im trying to display clicked datagrid values in textbox boxes. but now im getting this exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

my code on `datagrid_cellclick` event is this...

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    comboBox2.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    txtID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    txtName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    txtAddress.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    //txtPhone.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();          
    txtBalance.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is any of the cells empty (null)?

Comment: no, i insert int values in long text data type of field. is this the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is due to the fact that your `DataGridViewRow` Object doesn't get instanced.
It's probably because there is no access to your `dataGridView1` Object.
Using the prefix `this` incites that your `dataGridView1` object exists in the same class where your event is located, which is probably not the case.
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx

Try removing the keyword`this`, like so:

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{   
   txtID.Text = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); 
   txtPhone.Text = dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();    
}
```

or you can get Cell value by column name, like so:

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{   
   txtID.Text = dataGridView1["Id", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); 
   txtPhone.Text = dataGridView1["Phone", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();    
}
```

Comment: i did this code..
             if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                txtPhone.Text = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                txtID.Text = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
but it shows the selected cell value in both textboxes. i want to select a cell. and its whole row's data should display in textboxes.

Comment: did you have all column names?